# Rails 4 - capistrano 3 doesn't deploy last commits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano

We have a production environment for a Rails 4 app with Apache, Phusion Passenger, and Capistrano 3, and a remote bitbucket repository. The Capistrano's "cap production deploy" works well, and executes without errors. But when we go the "current" folder on the remote server, and do a "git log" command, the last commits of our remote repository aren't loaded.

We've tried the "git log" in the main folder of our app, same problem.

Our question is, who can we load the last commits of our repo into the production env ? Isn't Capistrano made to do it by default ?

Any idea of where it could come from ?

Here is the code of our Capfile, deploy.rb and deploy/production.rb files :

**Capfile**

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'


require 'rvm1/capistrano3'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/**/*.rb').each { |r| import r }
```

**deploy.rb**

```
lock '3.1.0'

set :application, 'XXXXXXX'
set :deploy_user, 'XXXXXXX'

set :repo_url, 'GIT_REPO_URL.XXXXXXX.git'

set :keep_releases, 5

set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_version, 'ruby-2.1.2'
set :default_env, { rvm_bin_path: '/usr/local/rvm/bin' }


set :bundle_dir, "/usr/local/bin"

set :ssh_options, {:forward_agent => true}

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/application.yml}

set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

set :tests, []

set(:config_files, %w(
  apache2.conf
  database.example.yml
  log_rotation
  unicorn.rb
  unicorn_init.sh
))

set :log_level, :debug

set :pty, true

set :assets_roles, [:app]

# which config files should be made executable after copying
# by deploy:setup_config
set(:executable_config_files, %w(
  unicorn_init.sh
))

# files which need to be symlinked to other parts of the
# filesystem. For example nginx virtualhosts, log rotation
# init scripts etc.
set(:symlinks, [
  {
    source: "apache2.conf",
    link: "/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"
  },
  {
    source: "unicorn_init.sh",
    link: "/etc/init.d/unicorn_#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"
  },
  {
    source: "log_rotation",
   link: "/etc/logrotate.d/#{fetch(:full_app_name)}"
  }
])


namespace :deploy do
   task :start do ; end
   task :stop do ; end
   desc 'Restart application'
   task :restart do
    on roles(:all), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      # Your restart mechanism here, for example:
      execute :touch, release_path.join('restart.txt')
    end
  end

  task :stop_node do
    on roles(:all), in: :sequence do
      #Stop the node_server
      execute "nohup node ./realtime/node_server.js &"
    end
  end
  task :restart_node do
    on roles(:all), in: :sequence do
      #Restart the node_server
      execute "nohup node ./realtime/node_server.js &"
    end

  end
end

# Bundle install configuration
set :bundle_without, %w{development test}.join(' ')
set :bundle_roles, :all
namespace :bundler do
  desc "Install gems with bundler."
  task :install do
    on roles fetch(:bundle_roles) do
      with RAILS_ENV: fetch(:environment) do
        within release_path do
          execute :bundle, "install", "--without #{fetch(:bundle_without)}"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
before 'deploy:updated', 'bundler:install'
before 'deploy:restart', 'bundler:install'
after 'deploy:updated', 'deploy:publishing'
after 'deploy:restart','deploy:restart_node'
```

**deploy/production.rb**

```
set :stage, :production
set :branch, "REPO_BRANCH"

set :full_app_name, "#{fetch(:application)}_#{fetch(:stage)}"
set :server_name, "XXXXXXX.com www.XXXXXXXX.com"

set :password, ask('Server password', nil)


server 'XXXXXX.com', user: 'XXXXXX', password: fetch(:password), port: 22,  roles: %w{web app}, primary: true

set :deploy_to, '/PATH/TO/APP'


set :rails_env, :production
set :environment, "production"

set :unicorn_worker_count, 5

set :enable_ssl, false
```

Comment: Have you pushed your local changes to github or equivalent?

Comment: Yes, I first push the local changes to the remote repo on bitbucket, and then I call "cap production deploy"

Comment: I would suggest you to check deployment logs if right branch is getting deployed.

Comment: @maximus I've checked the revisions.log and the specific branch is considered "deployed" as a release. But no changes are visible in the code. the commits are still not loaded (pulled)

Answer (score 12):

Looks like capistrano keeps a repo/ directory in /var/www/:appname/repo which caches the git repo, so if you change the repo capistrano won't auto-update.

Nuking the repo directory did the trick for me

Comment: Saved my day! Was debugging for a while now :-)

Comment: @Benoir you are a life saver :)

Answer (score 2):

You have set a specific branch for deployment (`set :branch, "REPO_BRANCH"`) and this branch is from the remote git repository. Make sure you have pushed the commits to the right branch of the bitbucket repo.

Comment: I've well pushed the local changes on this specific branch. But it doesn't work ... I can pull the changes directly on the production server by pulling the changes, but I want to make it automatically via Capistrano